# Is it possible to suppress bean injection?

Tags: java, wildfly, weld

I have an web app which is to be deployed on Wildfly 12. Included in the app is a third party jar with code similar to the following

```
class X
{
    @Inject private Y y = null;

    public void someMethod()
    {
        if (y == null)
            doSomething();
        else
            doSomethingElse(y);
    }
}
```

It's clear that the code has been written under the assumption that injection may fail and `y` can be `null`.

However Weld doesn't like this and I get a deployment error saying there is a unsatisfied deplendency for `y`. I can't modify the third party code and I don't want to supply a dependency for `y`. I would like the `doSomething()` branch to be taken.

Is it possible to tell Weld not to try and inject anything at this injection point?

Thanks.

Comment: You can let it throw the null pointer exception, catch it from outside, and from there launch "doSomething"? - maybe this is a stupid guess..

Comment: @AsierAranbarri There is no NPE. The error happens at deployment time, when Weld is 'validating' the injection point. It determines that it can't satisfy the dependendecy and halts the deployment.

Comment: that was a stupid guess then : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be overkill, but you can create a `producer` that always returns `null` for that `class`:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class YProducer {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped  
    public Y create() {
        return null;
    }

    public void destroy(@Disposes Y y) {
        //no-op
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to make some changes to get that to work. I replaced ApplicationScoped with ManagedBean (strange because Weld documentation states that ManagedBean is optional) and I had to remove RequestScoped. This means that all injections of Y will be null, not just the one I mentioned above, correct? I think I'm OK with that but I need to investigate.

Comment: That's correct, the `producer` will be responsible for all `@Injections` of this class.  I'm not sure if you can do something clever in the producer logic to know whether to return `null` or construct a Y instance depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is much more elegant solution (in Java8) taking advantage of the new `Optional` class:

```
@Inject
private Optional<Y> y;
```

The big difference is that y will never be null !
And you can then simply test its presence this way:

```
if ( y.isPresent() ) {
   doSomethingElse(y);      
} else {
   doSomething();
}
```

Other possibility using `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`

```
@Inject
private Instance<Y> instance;

try {
   y = instance.get();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify the third party code.